# Use jQuery to display html div couple time

Tags: jquery, html

I have this page where a box are hidden . this is it:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.window {
    display:none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    width: 400px; height: 245px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 15px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function show() {
    $(".window").fadeIn();
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button  onclick="show()">show</button>
<div class="window">ff</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so when i click the button, it shows a window. what i want is when i click 3 time the button i want 3 windows to appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, each time show() is called, you need to add a **new** DIV to the DOM.

I think you could do it like this:

```
$('.window:first').clone().appendTo(document.body).fadeIn();
return false;
```

Here's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sJLwD/

p.s. Next time, please make jsfiddle so your question is easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are trying to show div on first click and then from second click onwards clone div and add it to DOM.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        if($('.window').css('display')=='none'){
           $(".window").fadeIn(); // fadeIn div for first click
        }else{
            $(".window:first").clone().appendTo(document.body); // clone div and add it to DOM from second click onwards
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/9c5jj/1/)**

Comment: Agree, if he wants to first show the existing div, this is the way to go. You should however use (".window:first") when cloning, to avoid cloning all divs with the class ;)

Comment: @Unknown can you show me please how can i make those window float from left to right .

Answer (score 0):

If you want 3 windows you should firstly create them. This function create new window class block and then fade it in:

```
  $("button").on("click",function(){
    $("button").after('<div class="window">'+Math.random()*3+'</div>');
    $(".window").fadeIn();
  });
```

Here's jsbin: http://jsbin.com/hubahiqa/2/edit